# Suppresing a newline breaks JSX. Why?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
const addForm = <Formik> 
  {(props) => (
    <Form>
        (ommited...)
    </Form>
  )}
  </Formik>;
```

That works as expected. To my surprise, this (first newline suppresed) doesn't

```
const addForm = <Formik> {(props) => (
    <Form>
        (ommited...)
    </Form>
  )}
  </Formik>;
```

I get `Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

Is this expected behaviour? How can I understand it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the issue a bit more clearly if you look at the transpiled code. The [first code produces this](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQMRAJwLYwLwwDyqYCWA1gHwwBQMMA3gBQAOaIjEAlDhfdTfoRjK8-feiAwYiUAKYIAdAvbD8AegFCa7AL688a9JPIBuIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.8.4&externalPlugins=)

```
"use strict";

var addForm = React.createElement(Formik, null, function (props) {
  return React.createElement(Form, null, "(ommited...)");
});
```

And [the second code produces this](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQMRAJwLYwLwwDyqYCWA1gHwwDeAFAA5oi0QCUOF1AUDN_oRmVx5DqIDBiJQApggB0c5oO54A9HwHdmAX0Eq-pMgG4gA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.8.4&externalPlugins=)

```
"use strict";

var addForm = React.createElement(Formik, null, " ", function (props) {
  return React.createElement(Form, null, "(ommited...)");
});
```

The difference is that in the second case there's an extra `" "` as a child. That means the Formik component has two children, which isn't allowed.

So where's that extra space in the original code? It's the space between `<Formik>` and `{(props) => (`. If you delete that, you'll get the same behavior between both versions. The first example of code only has whitespace at the beginning of the lines, [which gets ignored](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#string-literals-1) when transpiling, but whitespace in the middle of a line is significant.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! This issue was driving me crazy. It's really surprising that Typescript doesn't throw any errors for this, causing a runtime issue.